# Can't figure out how to parse table row and certain columns and export to CSV

Tags: html, ruby, csv, html-parsing, nokogiri

First, let me admit that I'm a novice with Ruby.  I've only used it for a few days but with reasonable success.  I've been able to parse certain items that exist singularly in multiple HTML files and export to CSV; however, I'm stuck with parsing an entire table of data on multiple HTML files.  I was able to pull more than I needed but the resulting CSV export had all of each HTML file's data as an array within a single cell of the CSV.

Here is a simplified version of the data that I'm looking at (about 20-30 rows of this repeated on each page):

```
  <tbody id="threadbits_forum_406"> 
  <tr>
    <td class="alt1" id="td_threadstatusicon_######"> IMG </td> 
    <td class="alt2" align="center" valign="middle"> 
      <a href="http://I.NEED.THIS">
          <div style="height:75px; width:150px; overflow:hidden; background:url(http://I.NEED.THIS/TOO) center 25%;"> </div>
      </a> 
     </td> 
     <td class="alt1" id="td_threadtitle_######" title="blah">[...]</td> 
     <td class="alt2" title="blah"> <div class="smallfont" style="text-align:right; white-space:nowrap"> <a href="dontcare"> </a> </div> </td> 
     <td class="alt1" align="center">[...]</td> 
     <td class="alt2" align="center">[...]</td>
  </tr>
```

Since the class of the column is used a couple times, I'm having trouble understanding what CSS or XPATH tricks to use to pull out the background picture in the DIV and the HREF link that is on just that second column.  The DIV doesn't have a class like the one used in the other column.

If someone can  give me a little guidance, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Well, I can get the data with this: `thread = doc.css('tbody#threadbits_forum_406 tr td.alt2 a').map { |link| link['href'] }
thumb = doc.css('tbody#threadbits_forum_406 tr td.alt2 a div')

  @thread << thread
  @thumb << thumb` but the output for each page is within a single cell of the CSV.  I must be missing something to split that into separate rows...

Comment: Please edit your question and add your Ruby code so people can understand where you're starting from, which makes it easier for them to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.search('tr td:eq(2)').each do |td|
  puts td.at('a')['href'] # http://I.NEED.THIS
  if td.at('div')['style'] =~ /url\((.+)\)/
    puts $1 # http://I.NEED.THIS/TOO
  end
end
```